# Enable and disable debugging programmatically on react native

Tags: react-native

There is any way to programmatically control the chrome debugging? 
Realmjs has a big performance,  so i want to execute queries in a second jsworker with the debugger disabled, but when I start the debugger for the main worker the debugger for the second is automatically enabled too.

Comment: Could you provide a better idea of what kind of control your attempting? What goal would you like to accomplish here?

Comment: I have created a second RCTBridge which connect to a packager using port 8082. When I start the Chrome debugging using Shake/Cmd+D for the main bundle (which use packager on 8081), the RCTBridge using package on 8082 also enter in debug mode. 
I just want to prevent the second RCTBridge to enter in debug mode.

https://github.com/fabriciovergal/react-native-workers